# Proper group/permissions using MAMP site

Tags: permissions, mamp, dscl

I'm building a website using MAMP on OS10 *Leopard*. I'd like to be able to set an publicly accessible upload directory to 0775 and not 0777. I've tried a bunch of combinations in the "Permissions" panel in MAMP. I can get the site running under "www" group and 0775 works great for uploading, but then I cannot edit or delete the uploaded files via my filesystem user "ben." I tried adding myself to the "www" group but no luck there so far:

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/www GroupMembership ben
```

Any assistance or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm confident that I can get it working on my live server with 775, but I'd like to have a similar setup locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just running mysql/site under a different user that had permissions on the files.